# How to refresh a web page in Chrome (Ctrl+F5 analogue) on a device without menu button?

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have a Nexus 7 Android device with 4.2.2 and Chrome browser.

**How can one perform a deep refresh of a web page - analogue of <kbd>Ctrl+F5</kbd> hotkey on desktops?**

Please, notice that the device does not have a menu button.

According to the only [related question I've found here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9639/force-refresh-of-a-webpage-on-default-browser), the solution is to clear browser cache completely. I'd prefer more convenient and elegant solution.

Comment: How is the menu button (or lack thereof) related?

Comment: @eldarerathis, I saw some post on the Net, suggested to press Refresh tool button while holding Menu key.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I hadn't heard that one before.

Comment: Related on Stack Overflow: [How can I force a hard reload in Chrome for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571213/how-can-i-force-a-hard-reload-in-chrome-for-android).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bypassing per site cache:**

This needs a simple javascript code to be run in the address bar for bypassing the cache and fetch contents from the server instead of the browser cache. According to [this MDN page on Force reloading the current page from the server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location#Example_.232.3A_Force_reloading_the_current_page_from_the_server),

```
javascript:location.reload(true)
```

Enter the above code in the browser address bar and hit Enter key. This will fetch all the contents from the server instead of picking the elements cached in your browser(thus bypassing the browser cache).

**Bypass Cache data for all websites(Global cache)**

The above javascript work only for a specific website which you have currently opened. To clear all the website cache use the global browser cache data. You find this under,

```
Settings > Privacy > CLEAR BROWSING DATA
```

Select the "Cache" Checkbox (and other options like Browser data, Cookies, Password etc if you want) and select "Clear".

***Note:*** *While `Ctrl`+`F5` will cause the browser to throw out the cache and request new contents from the server, the server may ignore the `no-cache` header and serve a server-side cached page. Thus, even `Ctrl`+`F5` may return an old version of the page if the server ignores the no-cache header.*

**Incognito Mode:**

Browsing through incognito mode disables history and cache. So you can visit any site through incognito mode to request fresh content everytime.

---

For more interesting discussion on the what does `Ctrl`+`F5` or force refresh does,

Read this SO post, [What requests do browsers' “F5” and “Ctrl + F5” refreshes generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385367/what-requests-do-browsers-f5-and-ctrl-f5-refreshes-generate)

Comment: This [no longer works in Chrome 47](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571213/how-can-i-force-a-hard-reload-in-chrome-for-android#comment58185293_18591755).

Comment: Even after clearing browsing data, the deep refresh was not happening. I had to **kill and relaunch Chrome** in my Android phone to force it to get from cache. (As an afterthought, it looks like even after you clear cache on disk (presumably), the cache in memory is still around. Killing Chrome wipes the memory cache as well.) [PS: By "disk" I mean the permanent non-volatile storage aka flash memory.]

Answer (score 6):

On the left side of the URL, there is an info icon (i) or a lock icon. Click the icon and then [web site configuration].

You will find a trash icon to clear the cache of the current site, and alternatively a "restore preferences" button.

Working on Chrome for Android v71.

Comment: Not working on my S9+, Chrome build 73.0.3683.90.  I've hit the Clear & Reset option at least 15 times on a page I control (so I know what the code does quite well).  However, the JS running on the page I am loading is still an old version.

Comment: Well, It worked on my S9 perfectly, so I guess there is something going on specific to your case!  Could you please further loot at that?

Comment: I've now tried this on two different devices now, one using developer mode (my phone, since I'm a developer), and a friend's.  As well, I have tried on a tablet; no go there+.  As well, I even tried on my corporate iPhone using Chrome, and the same issue is there.  So from my perspective, you  seem lucky, more than I seem to have multiple flawed devices at my disposal.

Comment: Of course, the real problem is Chrome's / Android's funky behavior and hyper-aggressive caching.  It is like an incognito mode that does not work (speaking of which...that did not work properly either...)

Comment: Just checked that iPhone’s Chrome doesn’t have this option you are saying so I believe we are not speaking of the same thing: whats more there is none “clear & reset” in my Android’s Chrome. To triple check it, have tested my suggestion on a Xiaomi A1 working OK (notice it displays the local cache size of the page in KB). May be you need to close the tab (or try killing chrome). Otherwise I’m wondering what is the “trash button” of one specific site expected to do...?

Comment: Chrome Clear & Reset ==> (In Page) ==> Settings -> Site Settings -> All Sites -> Domain/Website -> Clear & Reset

As for what it is expected to do...it is expected to clear the cache and all old data related to that site.  Makes sense, no?

Comment: @IncorporealLogic: It may make sense, but the question specifically asked for a 'more convenient and elegant solution'. I certainly don't want to repeat a half-dozen fiddly steps every time I change a CSS file.

Answer (score 4):

I did not get any of these solutions to work. However, I have found a working solution.

**First, find out the CSS URL. In my case, it looked like this:**

```
/min/assets/css/style.min.css
```

**Write it in the address field, but also add a GET variable to it:**

```
/min/assets/css/style.min.css?hello
```

Hopefully, the GET variable is accepted. Because it's a new URL, it forces the CSS to reload. Now, go back to the site and the CSS should have been reloaded.

Answer (score 3):

On my Samsung tablet browsing with Chrome, type this in the address bar:

```
javascript:location.reload(true)
```

That should trigger a hard reload using Javascript. Now I do not have to wait for days to observe results of a change of code I made.
A new problem then is that typing on a tablet is not my favorite thing to do.

Instead of typing the above command I also tried to change to desktop mode and then back. That did not deep refresh.

Answer (score 3):

I use a **New Incognito Tab**. It works on other devices and browsers, as well. It avoids the local cache normally.

Notice that private sessions can still be considered concurrent, so you may have to close all incognito tabs to clear their cache.

Answer (score 1):

In the menu of the webpage, ask for the desktop version of the website. It will pull data from the server and the page will reload. After that, you can come back for the mobile version once again.

Comment: Not all websites offer mobile/desktop versions.

Comment: The current version of Chrome on Android has the option Request Desktop Site. Whether all sites honour that request or not, it's still an effective option in many cases. Trying this and finding it doesn't work is far easier and faster than clearing caches in settings.

Answer (score 1):

I need a way to clear the current cache or all cache from the same origin domain via JavaScript, so I can make sure the update rollout of my web app arrives without errors.

I also had no success on temporarily changing the cache meta tags in the HTML header.

Only on desktop and not automatable: Ctrl + R. Used to work to force reload to clear the cache. Now you have to press Ctrl + Shift + R or Shift + F5.

I wrote my own workaround `forceReload()` function that works on Windows Chrome, Chrome for Android, and Chromium:

```
window.forceReload = function() {
    if (!window.fetch) return document.location.reload(true);
    var els = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i = 0 ; i < els.length ; i++){
        var src = "";
        if (els[i].tagName == "A") continue;
        if (!src && els[i].src) src = els[i].getAttribute("src");
        if (!src && els[i].href) src = els[i].getAttribute("href");
        if (!src) continue;
        fetch(src, {cache: "reload"});
    }
    return document.location.reload(true);
};
```

This function will only reload contents that have been loaded on the current page. You can trigger it once on each of your clients after new updates are on the server, or simply add a working refresh button on your app.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. Fetch seems still experimental API, then probably another experimental Cache API could be handy as well.

Comment: Considering that Android.SE focuses more on issues from end-users, is the `forceReload()` function possible to be called from the browser directly?

Answer (score 0):

###### Follow this steps to connect your smartphone to your computer:

1. Open the **Developer Options** screen on your Android. See [Configure On-Device Developer Options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options).
2. Select **Enable USB Debugging**.
3. On your computer, open Chrome.
4. Go to `chrome://inspect#devices`.
5. Make sure that the **Discover USB devices** checkbox is enabled.
6. Connect your Android device directly to your development machine using a USB cable. The first time you do this, you usually see that DevTools has detected an offline device. If you see the model name of your Android device, then DevTools has successfully established the connection to your device.
7. If your device is showing up as **Offline**, accept the **Allow USB Debugging** permission prompt on your Android device.

(Copied from here [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/))

---

###### Now follow this steps to make `Ctrl` + `F5` reload:

1. On your smartphone open Chrome and go to your desired web site.
2. In DevTools tab on your computer click on **inspect** below the web site url.
3. In opened windows (where you can see the mobile screen) press `Ctrl` + `F5`.

Comment: Doesn't work for Chrome 94.0.4606.81 under Android and Linux, except when Network→Disable Cache is ticked.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: install a full keyboard app (e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard ), tap the address bar to open the keyboard, then press shift+F5

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a version parameter in the css/js url loaded, since every revisitor might have some problems.

Found this solution in another discussion, but I don't know the url. It worked fine for me :-)

Comment: This is similar to [Jens Tornell's approach](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/197775/44325) by using the GET parameter with a different value to break the cache, though the problem is how to do it efficiently (and possibly for all resources), because this site focuses on end-users, not developers' POV...

Answer (score -1):

Pull down on a page to reload it, it comes incorporated to Chrome for smartphones.

Comment: While this feature is most recently added to Chrome broswers(ver.41 above) it wont be availabe in the older versions. So this feature may or may not work. And more importantly, this does just reloads the page in the normal way but the OP asks for a hard refresh.

Comment: It's not specified if the requiered solution is under a point of view of android or coding

Comment: Couldn't understand what you mean by that. But this answer doesn't  convice me that it will provide a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: This "answer" is literally just telling people you can perform a *regular* refresh by pulling down on the page. OP's question however was about doing a "hard refresh",  CTRL+F5 equivalent on the PC.

Answer (score -3):

To the left of the web address window you are visiting is a nearly circular arrow.

Comment: I don't believe this does a deep refresh like Stan is asking for.